# How can I retrieve value from my component

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have created a form component. In that form component I also have a range component.
I was wondering how can I retrieve my value from my range component and more generally how can I interact with a component from outside it. (even if the goal is to encapsulate things)
I don't know if there are components like that somewhere but for now I just want to learn how it works. thanks !

Here is my code

index.html

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>data_generator_front</title>
  </head>

  <body>   

    <my-form></my-form>

    <div class="results"></div>

    <script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

index.dart

```dart
import "package:angular/angular.dart";
import "package:angular/application_factory.dart";
import "package:data_generator_front/component/my_form.dart";
import "package:data_generator_front/component/range.dart";

@Injectable()
class RootContext {
    String myProperty = "jeahhhhhhhh";
    void method1() {
        print("method1");
    }
}

main() {
    applicationFactory()
      .rootContextType(RootContext)
      .addModule(new DateFormModule())
      .addModule(new RangeComponentModule())
      .run();
}
```

my_form.html

```dart
<form>
    <range name="years" value="myProp"></range>
    <div>
       <label>Random:</label>
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="random">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Go !">
    </div>
</form>
```

my_form.dart

```dart
library my_form;
import "package:angular/angular.dart";

@Component(selector: "my-form", templateUrl: "my_form.html", exportExpressions: const ["submit"])
class DateFormComponent {

   @NgOneWay("random")
   bool random;

   submit() {
      print("hello");      
   }

}

class DateFormModule extends Module {
   DateFormModule() {
      bind(DateFormComponent);
   }
}
```

range.dart

```dart
import "package:angular/angular.dart";

@Component(selector: "range", templateUrl: "range.html")
class RangeComponent {
   @NgAttr("name")
   String name;

   @NgOneWay("range_begin")
   String range_begin;

   @NgOneWay("range_end")
   String range_end;

   List<String> ranges = [];

   addRange() {
      ranges.add("$range_begin-$range_end");
      range_begin = "";
      range_end = "";
   }

   info(){
      print(range_begin);
      print(range_end);
      print(ranges);
      print(ranges.reduce((begin, item){
      return begin += ",$item";
   }));
   }

}

class RangeComponentModule extends Module {
   RangeComponentModule() {
      bind(RangeComponent);
   }
}
```

range.html

```dart
<div>
   <label>{{name}}:</label>
   <input type="text" placeholder="begin" size="8" ng-model="range_begin">
   <input type="text" placeholder="end" size="8" ng-model="range_end">
   <input type="submit" value="add" ng-click="addRange()" >
   <input type="submit" value="info" ng-click="info()" >
   <input type="submit" value="value" ng-click="range()" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess changing `NgOneWay` to `NgTwoWay` should do the trick so the value gets updated inside the component. To get the value outside of the component bind

```dart
<range name="years" value="{{myProp}}"></range>
```

and create a field in your `my-form` component.

```dart
@NgTwoWay('myProp')
var myProp;
```

Alternatively you can implement `ScopeAware` to get the scope and then use `scope.emit`, `scope.broadcast`, `scope.on...` to send the data as event on submit to send it across the DOM not just to the immediate parent/child

Answer (score 0):

almost :) but it's only works one way

I initialize the property in my_form.dart then the my_form.html has the value binded and finally the range component can use the value at init time.

but when I change the code inside the component the value is not binded anymore with the my_form.dart

here is the code

range.html didn't change

my_form.dart

```dart
library my_form;
import "package:angular/angular.dart";

@Component(selector: "my-form", templateUrl: "my_form.html", exportExpressions: const ["submit"])
class DateFormComponent {

   @NgOneWay("random")
   bool random;

   @NgTwoWay("v1")
   String v1 = "eee";

   submit() {
      print(random);
      print(v1);
   }

}

class DateFormModule extends Module {
   DateFormModule() {
      bind(DateFormComponent);
   }
}
```

my_form.html

```dart
<form>
    <range name="years" value="{{v1}}"></range>
    <div>
       <label>Random:</label>
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="random">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Go !" ng-click="submit()">
    </div>
</form>
```

range.dart

```dart
import "package:angular/angular.dart";

@Component(selector: "range", templateUrl: "range.html")
class RangeComponent {
   @NgAttr("name")
   String name;

   @NgAttr("value")
   String value;  

   @NgOneWay("range_begin")
   String range_begin;

   @NgOneWay("range_end")
   String range_end;

   List<String> ranges = [];

   addRange() {
      ranges.add("$range_begin-$range_end");
      range_begin = "";
      range_end = "";
      value = ranges.reduce((begin, item){
         return begin += ",$item";
      });
   }

   info(){
      print(range_begin);
      print(range_end);
      print(ranges);
      print(value);
   }

}

class RangeComponentModule extends Module {
   RangeComponentModule() {
      bind(RangeComponent);
   }
}
```

thanks for helping anyway :)

Comment: `@NgAttr("value") String value;` Should be `@NgTwoWay`. `@NgAttr` is only to bind literal values.

Comment: By changing like you said I have an exception: Parser Error: Unexpected token {, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 2 in [{{v1}}]
but without the {{}} it works. I thought {{}} was needed to have binding ?

Comment: Ok I just saw that (at)NgAttr, (at)NgOneWay and (at)NgTwoWay bind instance property with DOM attribut ... cool thx :)

Comment: `@NgAttr` is for literal values, `{{}}` is for expressions.